# React Native image import with import() instead of require()

Tags: typescript, react-native, webpack, babeljs, dynamic-import

Is there a way of importing an asset in React-Native dynamically with `import(...)` instead of `require(...)`?

We are using `@typescript-eslint/recommended` and I'd like to keep the rule `@typescript-eslint/no-var-requires` enabled, which is marking this as an error.

The way we do it now:

```
const foo = require("../path/to/foo.png")
```

How I want to do it:

```
const foo = import("../path/to/foo.png")
```

It would also be ok if I could just use normal ESM import syntax rather than require. Is there any way?

Answer (score 3):

React Native's Metro bundler doesn't support dynamic imports https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/52, so what you're asking is not possible. (Btw there are now inline requires which you can use e.g. for https://reactnative.dev/docs/ram-bundles-inline-requires but that's a different thing).

On a separate note, in your example `const foo = require('.../foo.png')` is actually a *static* require; the equivalent using ES6 modules would be `import foo from '.../foo.png'`. That might actually work, although I think it's better to use `<Image source={require('..')} />` directly rather than introduce another variable.